# Fetch first N rows including tie values MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| id  | Name  |Votes|
+-----+-------+-----+
|  1  | Joe   | 36  |
|  2  | John  | 34  |
|  3  | Mark  | 42  |
|  4  | Ryan  | 29  |
|  5  | Jay   | 36  |
|  6  | Shawn | 39  |
+-----+-------+-----+
```

For this example, what I want is to retrieve the rows with the first 3 highest votes. However, if you'll notice, there are two rows with the same vote count. So this should be the result:

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| id  | Name  |Votes|
+-----+-------+-----+
|  3  | Mark  | 42  |
|  6  | Shawn | 39  |
|  1  | Joe   | 36  |
|  5  | Jay   | 36  |
+-----+-------+-----+
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you guys downvote my question, please state the reason why so I will be able to change something if needed. I need help here, not downvotes.

Comment: Not the one who downvoted. Just a suggestion: you can try the following strategy: (1) get the top three scores, and (2) join this result back to the table itself to retrieve all entries with these scores.

Comment: Thanks @Terry! Nice idea. Haven't thought of that. I was thinking of using LIMIT, which is definitely not the solution. You can post it as an answer, I'll surely accept it.

Comment: I don't see why the downvote, but it's a totally legit question. If I'm new to MySQL I wouldn't know I could join a table back to itself, too! (Trust me I've been there and done that)

Comment: I do accept downvotes but it's annoying when you get one but you have no idea why. Anyways, thanks for helping! That was all I needed.

Comment: Well @Koen., At first, I was just doing something like this: `select * from table order by votes desc limit 3` but since it will ONLY return 3 rows, the fourth one will not be included. Gladly, Terry gave me an idea.

Comment: @fmpsagara Using an `INNER JOIN` would be the trick ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78f0/10. See my answer for further explanation, but I hope it works for you.

Comment: @fmpsagara what I meant to say with that question; someone probably downvoted because you didn't state what you have tried yourself.

Comment: @Koen Sometimes it does the community more benefit through guidance with a helping hand instead of unexplained downvotes. Some people might not be accustomed to language-specific terminology when new to a programming language, or might not be able to succinctly describe their issue. I think OP did a great job in formulating a problem statement + sample data and desired output to boot—most questions on SO don't even satisfy any of these.

Comment: I was thinking of putting a query, but it seems to be useless since I know it's not the right one lol, so I opted to put a sample data. Anyways, thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to perform an `INNER JOIN`, using the table back on itself. First, you want to select the top 3 unique/distinct scores, and this can be done by using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Votes FROM mytable ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 3
```

Now that you have obtained the top 3 scores, you want to join it back to the original table:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT Votes FROM mytable ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 3) AS topvotes
ON
  topvotes.Votes = t1.Votes
ORDER BY t1.Votes DESC
```

Refer to a simple diagram for the strategy:

[image: INNER JOIN strategy]

For this query to be efficient, you will want to index the `Votes` column so that the subquery can fish out distinct votes quickly ;)

Here is a proof-of-concept SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78f0/10

Comment: Thanks so much @Terry! Such a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient, but I think this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE score IN(SELECT score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3)
```

Although this can yield an error about limit not being supported in subqueries.

A workaround;

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE score IN(SELECT * FROM (SELECT score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3) AS t)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @Koen.